# How to join two SELECT statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join following two querys. But second query's where conditions should not effect the first query's result.how can i do this?

Query 1

```
SELECT ed.name, COUNT(ej.designation) AS actual
FROM emp_designations ed 
JOIN emp_job_details ej on ed.id = ej.designation 
WHERE ed.department = 4 
GROUP BY ej.designation,ed.name
```

Query 2

```
SELECT ej.designation, COUNT(*) as present 
FROM daily_attendances da 
JOIN emp_job_details ej ON da.emp_id = ej.emp_id
WHERE da.in_time != '' AND da.date = '2017-06-02' 
GROUP BY ej.designation
```

Result for Query 1
[image]

Result for Query 2
[image]

In designation column in query 2  12,13,14 equals to Cutting Incharge,patern maker, Supervisor.

I want to join these two tables

Comment: Hint: `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Please show sample results for the two queries and the combined result you are after.

Comment: Take a look at `UNION`

Comment: Query 1 looks wrong. You have a field (`ej.designation`) in both an aggregate column and in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT ej.designation, ed.name, COUNT(ej.designation) AS actual, COUNT(da.emp_id) as present
FROM emp_designations ed 
JOIN emp_job_details ej on ed.id = ej.designation 
LEFT JOIN daily_attendances da 
    ON (da.emp_id = ej.emp_id AND da.in_time != '' AND da.date = '2017-06-02')
WHERE ed.department = 4 
GROUP BY ej.designation ,ed.name
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood, the first auery lists the name and a count of designation.
The second query is counting all attendances per designation.

If you want to `JOIN` those two queries, your link would be the `designation`.
I used the SUM & COALSESCE, as the final resultset will be grouped by the designation again - so i have to use an aggregate function over the count of present. COALESCE will return 0 instead of NULLS. Just in case there is no match between the resultsets.

Is this what you where looking for? If not, just add an comment.

```
    SELECT ed.name
          ,COUNT(ej.designation) AS actual
          ,SUM(COALESCE(pres.present,0)) AS present
      FROM emp_designations ed 
INNER JOIN emp_job_details ej 
        ON ed.id = ej.designation 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
          SELECT ej.designation
               ,COUNT(*) as present 
            FROM daily_attendances da 
      INNER JOIN emp_job_details ej 
              ON da.emp_id = ej.emp_id
           WHERE da.in_time != '' 
             AND da.date = '2017-06-02' 
        GROUP BY ej.designation
        ) pres
       ON pres.designation = ej.designation     
     WHERE ed.department = 4 
  GROUP BY ej.designation
          ,ed.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNION if you want to eliminate any duplicate records being rendered. If the duplicates don't matter, try UNION ALL, that will help you out.

Read up about these commands at:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html